# How to Filter dataset for two column

Tags: c#, dataset

I have datatable which is binded with grid as following
Table1

```
Id Type Desc 
1  A    ABC 
2  A    XYZ 
1  B    QRS 
3  B    123
```

Based upon the user selection on Grid row following table is generating. 
Table2

```
Id  Type
1   A
1   B
2   A
```

This second table can grow till first table.

I have to find out filtered rows from table 1 based upon selection of grid (or output as table2)

I have following questions

1. Should i create second table2 from rows selection of grid to filter table1
2. If yes, then how to filter with these two table
3. If No answer of question1 then what is best way.

I am using dEV eX GRID.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a dataview and set correctly the RowFilter property to filter your first datable
    with filter value of second table,for instance:

```
dataView.RowFilter = "Id IN (1, 2) AND Type = A"

for sure you have to make it dynamic so you can scan each row and
```

make your rowFilter that is id = 1 and type = A or id = 2 and type = A etc...
    here a link to understand how use it:
    http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/